# How do you override a class from the Laravel source code?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, laravel-echo

I need to make a change to the retrieveUser() function within Illuminate/Broadcasting/Broadcasters/Broadcaster.php.

The change works if I edit the class directly, but I have heard that you are not supposed to do that because it is difficult to track changes to the source code and because it will get overwritten when upgrading Laravel or when pushing to production.

So if I wanted to write my own modified retrieveUser() function for the Broadcaster class (it happens to be an abstract class which implements BroadcasterContract), then where and how would I do that?

Original function:

```
    /**
     * Retrieve the authenticated user using the configured guard (if any).
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  string  $channel
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function retrieveUser($request, $channel)
    {
        $options = $this->retrieveChannelOptions($channel);

        $guards = $options['guards'] ?? null;

        if (is_null($guards)) {
            return $request->user();
        }

        foreach (Arr::wrap($guards) as $guard) {
            if ($user = $request->user($guard)) {
                return $user;
            }
        }
    }
```

New function:

```
protected function retrieveUser($request, $channel)
    {
        $options = $this->retrieveChannelOptions($channel);

        $guards = $options['guards'] ?? null;

        if (is_null($guards)) {
            $token = $request->header('Token');
            $id = Crypt::decrypt($token);
            $user = User::find($id);
            return $user;
        }

        foreach (Arr::wrap($guards) as $guard) {
            if ($user = $request->user($guard)) {
                return $user;
            }
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE**
As @ggdx pointed out in the comments, I can override the class by doing `class yourClass extends Illuminate\Broadcasting\Broadcasters\Broadcaster`
However, I still don't know *where* to put this new class within the Laravel framework. I tried creating the new class in the /app route, but that did not work.

Comment: `class yourClass extends Illuminate\Broadcasting\Broadcasters\Broadcaster` with your one containing the method you seek to override. Pretty basic inhertiance stuff. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php

Comment: Thanks @ggdx - and you put this class in your /app root or elsewhere? If you want to post this as an answer instead of a comment, I can mark it as correct to give you the credit.

Comment: @ggdx Getting Laravel to **use** the modified class may take a bit more effort.

Comment: Thanks @ceejayoz - that is what I would like to accomplish, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @ceejayoz  No, you are completely, completely wrong. It doesn't. At all. You import it as you would any other framework (it's JUST php after all)

Comment: @ggdx Look, if Laravel's doing `new Illuminate\Broadcasting\Broadcasters\Broadcaster` internally, and you extend a class off `Illuminate\Broadcasting\Broadcasters\Broadcaster`, Laravel's not going to know that you extended the class in some other file. It'll keep happily using the built-in one. For that, you need another bit of code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32876280/laravel-how-to-register-custom-broadcaster

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel - How to register custom broadcaster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32876280/laravel-how-to-register-custom-broadcaster)

Comment: @ggdx - I have to agree with ceejayoz on this one. I built the new class which extends the original class, but Laravel doesn't use it.

I did try creating a custom broadcaster, but that only extends ```Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\Broadcaster``` instead of the one I want to extend which is ```Illuminate\Broadcasting\Broadcasters\Broadcaster```

Perhaps there is another way to register a custom broadcaster that also allows for the other Broadcaster route to be extended, but I still haven't figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what you are trying to accomplish. But I think making a custom driver for a guard will do what you want. Looking at the docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication#adding-custom-guards

You can do this in the boot method of your AuthServiceProvider.

```
Auth::viaRequest('custom-token', function ($request) {
    return User::find(Crypt::decrypt($request->header('Token')));
});
```

Also, make sure to select it as the driver for your guard in your auth.php config file.

Comment: Ok thanks so much for your response, let me give this a try and I will report back. Cool that you can pull in the $request header in the driver. I had no idea.

Comment: Thanks again - I tried adding the ```Auth::viaRequest``` to AuthServiceProvider and also the ```custom-token``` guard to auth.php, but I only got 401 errors: Client can not be authenticated. Even when I tried manually typing in the URL: 127.0.0.1:8000/broadcasting/auth?token=1 it still said I was not authenticated (this attempt is without the encryption).